# Could not load file or assembly on installing the winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have designed a winform application and with the help of Visual Studio 2010 i made a setup of the application.In the application i have used three external .dlls i.e Mysql, Itextsharp and Epplus.Every thing is fine while working in visual studio but as soon as i installed the setup and tried to access the application from there i got a very strange error i.e  `Could not load file or assembly` for the other two dlls i.e `Itextsharp and Epplus` while there is no error for mysql.Also i did a cross check of the installation folder and i can see all the dlls used in my application to be available there ..

Actually i cross checked from the visual studio Command prompt and got to know that the application is trying to search these dlls at wrong place ..Why the application is searching it at wrong place ? How come it is getting `Mysql.dll` at the right folder and place and why it is searching other two at wrong place and folder..?

Please help me to find out ..what can be the possible reason for this strange error and what can be the solution..
Thanks..

Update

```
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Vikas/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/ECV/

LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Vikas\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ECV\ECVNEW.exe.Config
```

Comment: @HansPassan I have used these two dlls before also in other projects and they are working fine there ..Actually i crossed checked from the visual studio Command prompt and got to know that the application is trying to search these dlls at wrong place ..Why the application is searching it at wrong place ?How come it is able to get `Mysql.dll`

Comment: You of course cannot get a good answer when you don't put this information in your question.  Tell us *everything* you know.

Comment: @HansPassant I updated my post with these and that's all that i know and i have tried so far

Comment: What is that file path it should be looking at and what is the path that it's actually looking at? Also, are you sure it's loading the Mysql dll from where you think it is, could it be in the GAC?

Comment: @Nanhydrin Please see my post i updated the path where the application is searching the .dlls This is where my application is trying to search .dlls

Comment: And what is the install path for the application? And what is in the config file at the install path?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the instalation is not copying all references. have you checked in the top references (the winform project) if you set the copy local =true for all the references you need, or even you can install them into the GAC.

[image]

Comment: Copy Local is true in my application and Also i did a cross check of the installation folder and i can see all the dlls used in my application to be available there.The only difference is that `Mysql.dll` is present in `C:/Programfiles/` while other two is present in the `Desktop` but on checking these two dlls in the installation folder i can see there presenece ...Any suggestion

Comment: are the target instalation of the same arquicteure x86 or 64? or different dll version?

Comment: The application installation folder is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EV`

Comment: have you tried to remove all dlls and replace them by debug folder.

Comment: No , i have not tried this ...I have one question Why `Mysql.dll` is working and these two are not working in the same installation folder from the same appication

Comment: have you tried to check the event viewer log? IF there is a reference problem it should be there Ctr+X and type eventvwr

Comment: Actually i dont know how to do it ..Also i would like to tell one more thing that is my application starts with Admin rights only.Can this be issue ?

Answer (score 0):

for each dll that you are getting the errors change  `Copy Local` property to `true`.

If you don't do this operation when you build project these dll aren't copied to the bin folder and if the PC where you use the program doesn't have these dll the program will fail

**update**

check if your project is targetting .net 4.5, maybe the dlls are targetting .net 4.0

**update 2**

go to solution explorer --> Properties --> build tab

set platform target to 'Any CPU' to ensures that your application will work on both 32 and 64bit computers.

Comment: Copy Local is true in my application and Also i did a cross check of the installation folder and i can see all the dlls used in my application to be available there...

Comment: target is .net 4.0 only

Comment: try with this line as first line in Main method `Environment.CurrentDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);`

Comment: Already tried this as i got this solution from the `SO` answer but no luck

Comment: try putting these ddls at the same level of the exe file

Comment: Can you please explain same level of the exe file ?

Comment: in the folder where you have "app.exe" put also the dlls that cause errors

Comment: They are present there since the application got install

Comment: i would like to tell one more thing that is my application starts with Admin rights only.Can this be issue ?

Comment: yes, so it's just a permission problem to get the dlls!

Comment: But i am launching the application from admin rights only ..And why is my `mysql.dll` is working fine when it is present in the same folder and application ?

Comment: go to for example to itextsharp dll from the pc where the application is installed. Select Properties and check if there is a message like this `This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer`

Comment: No its not there ...Every thing is fine in property

Comment: is the version of dll in the appconfig equal to the version that you are using in your bin folder?

Comment: Actually Except ` <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>` there is nothing in my application `app.config` file